# There is a blank area at the bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want create a UITableView in the viewController's view, but not the hole screen.

```
    _myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _myTableView.dataSource = self;
    _myTableView.delegate = self;
    [_myTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyKuCunTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:kMyKuCunCell];
    [self.view addSubview:_myTableView];

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
MyKuCunTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kMyKuCunCell];
if (!cell) {
    NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyKuCunTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib lastObject];
   }
    return cell;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0f;
}
```

but something is wrong: there is a blank when I scroll to the top! Please notice the indicator.

How it happens? I haven't seen this in the past when the UITableView is full of the screen.
(The red is the blank area)

I have found the solution,seeing No.2 answer. Thanks all!

[image]

Comment: i am not get in your question

Comment: I did not understand your question, do you want the tableView to be on all of the screen of not?

Comment: are you using auto layout ?

Comment: I don't want the TableView is full of screen because I will put some buttons under the UITableView.@YuviGr

Comment: No, I turn off it all the xib and the storyboard. I did not use the storyboard, just xibs and codes.@V-Xtreme

Comment: show your bottom button frame bro

Comment: SOLUTION IS HERE : In your view list select tablview and set it to below or above the darkblack item.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set these two property to 0

```
@property (nonatomic)          CGFloat                     sectionHeaderHeight;   // will return the default value if unset

@property (nonatomic)          CGFloat                     sectionFooterHeight;   // will return the default value if unset
```

and these two to nil

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableHeaderView;                           // accessory view for above row content. default is nil. not to be confused with section header

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableFooterView;                           // accessory view below content. default is nil. not to be confused with section footer
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Hope it helps!